# Swift тестирование оффер кодов в sandbox

Tags: swift

Опубликовал приложение в аппсторе, сгенерировал кода в AppStoreСonnect

Вызываю окно для применения кода

```
 SKPaymentQueue.default(). PresentCodeRedemptionSheet()
```

Ввожу код и получаю ошибку:

```
 To use the subscription offer, install ${My app name}.
```

Почему-то не хочет при дебаг сборке теститься, как собственно мне потестить тогда ? я что- то не правильно сделал ?

Comment: Попробуйте поставить сборку из Testflight.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev так же :( хотя на разных версиях iOS показывает по разному этот экран, где то показывает экран с кнопкой применить, но действия никакого нет. Я смог потестить только через xCode - если там локально добавить подписки и эти кода. А вообще, через тестфлайт должно теститься ?

Comment: Необязательно, можно и через прод, конечно. Главное, чтобы подписки были настроены.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev можете подсказать: в проде тестирую и такой баг: после применения оффер кода, показывает окно с удачной покупкой и кнопкой "перейти в приложение" и тут есть загвоздка: на первом устройстве "перейти в приложение" - нет действия, на другом устройстве при нажатии на "перейти в приложение" - окно закрылось, но ничего не произошло, я предполагаю, что Элл не уведомила меня через SKPaymentTransactionObserver. На третьем устройстве я решил нажать кнопку "закрыть" после удачного окна - и там все ок, элл уведомило приложение через SKPaymentTransactionObserver и подписку дало. Что не так?

Comment: в первом устройстве мб я слишком рано тестил (буквально сразу после аппрува) - мб в этом дело. Во втором - не понятно. Вывод такой: если нажать "закрыть" - то все ок, Элл уведомило приложение все засчиталось, а если нажать на кнопку "перейти в приложение" - окно закрывается и ничего не происходит

Comment: Нет, не сталкивался. Попробуйте настроить подписки через апи RevenueCat. Возможно, это более удобный инструмент для подписок. У них есть бесплатный вариант.